# Proving $\left(\sum_{k=1}^na_kb_kc_k\right)^4\le\left(\sum_{k=1}^na_k^4\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^nb_k^2\right)^2\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}c_k^4\right) $

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

For arbitrary real $a_k$, $b_k$, $c_k$ we have to prove the following inequality

$$\left( \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k b_k c_k\right)^4 \le \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n} {a_k}^4\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n} {b_k}^2\right)^2 \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n} {c_k}^4\right) $$

I think this can be proved using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, but I'm not able to apply it properly. Can anyone help me prove this?

My attempt:
$$\begin{align}
\left(\left(\sum_{k=1}^n (a_kb_k)(c_k)\right)^2\right)^2
&\le \left(\sum_{k=1}^n (a_kb_k)^2\right)^2\left(\sum_{k=1}^n c_k^2\right)^2 \tag1\\
&\le \left(\sum_{k=1}^n (a_k^2b_k^2)\right)^2 \left(\sum_{k=1}^n c_k^2\right)^2 \tag2\\
&\le \left(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^4\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^n b_k^4\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^n c_k^2\right)^2 \tag3
\end{align}$$

But this is not what exactly is asked to prove. Can we just change the notations or use commutativity of real numbers here?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I added my attempt to the question can you check it @MATHBOI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, write $b_k=\sigma_k|b_k|$ where $\sigma_k$ is the sign of $b_k$ (considering $0$ is positive)

Then you have $$a_kb_kc_k=a_k\sigma_k|b_k|c_k=\left(\sigma_ka_k\right)\left(\sqrt{|b_k|}\right)^2c_k$$ and you can apply the CS inequality twice (and using $\sigma_k^2=1$) :
$$\begin{align}
\left(\left(\sum_{k=1}^n {a_kb_kc_k}\right)^2\right)^2
&=\left(\left(\sum_{k=1}^n {\left(\sigma_ka_k\sqrt{|b_k|}\right)\left(\sqrt{|b_k|}c_k\right)} 
                                              \right)^2\right)^2 \\
&\le\left(\sum_{k=1}^n{\left(\sigma_ka_k\right)^2|b_k|}\right)^2\left(\sum_{k=1}^n{|b_k|c_k^2}\right)^2 \\
&\le\left(\sum_{k=1}^n{a_k^4}\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^n{b_k^2}\right)
       \left(\sum_{k=1}^n{b_k^2}\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^n{c_k^4}\right) \\
&=\left(\sum_{k=1}^n{a_k^4}\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^n{b_k^2}\right)^2
                        \left(\sum_{k=1}^n{c_k^4}\right)
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Start from RHS and break it up into multiple CS instances, like so
$$\left(\sum_k a_k^2|b_k| \right)^2\leqslant \left(\sum_k a_k^4 \right)\left(\sum_k b_k^2 \right)$$

Can you come up with the last two CS applications to complete the proof?